# Prevent PHP from including files from other sites directories

Tags: nginx, php-fpm, user-permissions

Currently I am running nginx 1.0.11 and PHP-FPM. Each site has it's own user/group and has their home directory in `/srv/www/...`. I have the PHP-FPM pools set to run as the sites' user and group on separate ports (9001 for site1, 9002 for site2...). Does this do anything to help with security?

nginx is running as www-data:www-data. Currently if I have a PHP script in site1 `(/srv/www/site1.com/www/public_html/script.php)`I can do this `include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/../../../site2.com/www/public_html/index.html";` and read that site's files.

How can I prevent this? I looked into `chroot` but each site's home directory has symlinks to `/dotfiles` that I need to keep and I assume nginx will need to access logs at `/var/logs/nginx/...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [open_basedir](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir). There are a couple known ways to get around it, but these can be prevented in the config.

Why symlinks instead of hard links on the dotfiles?

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into it. Symlinks because I have some directories in my /dotfiles that I am linking. No way to use `chroot` with symlinks?